# Prepending [DEBUG] to set -x, and [ERROR] to other stderr content, in shell script's logs

Tags: bash, shell, unix, logging

Well i want to log all the steps of execution of a bash file.

I know this can be done through

```
        set -x
```

But want i want to do is wen a error occurs i want it to be prepend error to the line before redirecting

ex:

```
   [ERROR] cp cannot stat.....
```

Rest all lines should be redirected as

```
         [DEBUG] ....
```

SO that the log contains clear details of which is an error and which is a debug line.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: You need to write your own function to print error/info/debug logs based on the return codes you capture. You may want to check `$?` and how you could use it for customized log printing.

Comment: The errors occured during execution of a script cannot be distinguished from the steps of execution on set -x ? @PS.

Comment: I do not think so. But I hope you will solve this query soon.

Comment: As a rule, by the way -- a title should be sufficiently specific that it contains enough information that someone can tell, *only from the title*, if they have the same problem it addresses. I've tried to edit it appropriately here; see also http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Use `PS4` to use a format string that distinguishes `set -x` output. For instance:

```
PS4=' [DEBUG] ${BASH_SOURCE##*/}:${LINENO}:'
exec 2> >(while IFS= read -r line; do
           if [[ $line = " [DEBUG] "* ]]; then
             printf '%s\n' "$line"
           else
             printf ' [ERROR] %s\n' "$line"
           fi
          done)
set -x
```

This prefaces every line of output from `set -x` with `[DEBUG]`, followed by the source file's name and the line number being executed; and prepends  `[ERROR]` to every line on stderr *not* containing a `[DEBUG]` marker.

---

You could also (with bash 4.x or newer) redirect `set -x` output through a different pipeline using `BASH_XTRACEFD`, but this has substantial caveats. That said, it would look something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
# note that the below requires bash 4.1 at minimum

exec {real_stderr}>&2
exec 2> >(while IFS= read -r line; do printf ' [ERROR] %s\n' "$line"; done >&"$real_stderr")
PS4=' [DEBUG] ${BASH_SOURCE##*/}:${LINENO}:'
exec {BASH_XTRACEFD}>&$real_stderr
set -x
```

**However**: Redirecting these through file descriptors makes their writes asynchronous, so they can be written out-of-order. For that reason, this approach is ill-advised if you intend your debug and stderr streams to go to the same ultimate destination.